# VSS Writer : RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE breaks log shipping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping, corruption

Log shipping has been working for a very long time, but now and then it breaks. I found it sometimes breaks (causes the transaction log to become corrupt and I get the message : "media family on device is incorrectly formed" of "transaction log is corrupted") when

```
Microsoft SQL Server VSS Writer
```

executes

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM VIRTUAL_DEVICE='{xxx}' WITH SNAPSHOT,COMMIT_DIFFERENTIAL_BASE,BUFFERCOUNT=1,BLOCKSIZE=1024.
```

Sometimes it would break all the DBs on log shipping. Other times just one. Other times 2 DBs.

Why would this break log shipping?

Why is it executing - what is the use of "Restore VerifyOnly from VirtualDevice"?

Is it an external instruction to execute this?

Should I disable "restore verifyonly fom virtual device" somehow?

I am clueless here and will take any advice please.

Comment: Restore verifyonly does not breaks LSN, it might be the third party tool you are using to take backup. To test this disable VSS writer so that such backup does not happens, ofcourse you need to take permission from management before disablinf, and see if LS is affected.

Comment: OK I did disable the windows service (on the machine that runs SQL instance) now, will monitor. Previously it was VEEAM which broke the log shipping, but this time it was not VEEAM